# Pandas function printing indices and value when it shouldn't

Tags: pandas

When I run df.loc[zone] on a dataframe with multi-index, the value that's printed is preceeded by the two indices (zone and run).  When I run df.shape I get a shape of (1,).  For example:

```
df

    zone  run
    1     3       67.889616
    2     3      167.131685
    3     3       20.493902

zone=3
print(df.loc[zone])
```

displays:

```
zone  run
3     3       20.493902
```

expect:

```
20.493902
```

Comment: I'm confused because I would think given that display and the shape you have a Series with a MultiIndex. But `Series.loc[zone]` should remove the outer level when you slice and it doesn't seem to. What is `type(df)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loc on dataframe takes in full index qualifier and returns value in any column.
So for a multiindex dataframe with index (x1, x2), the right syntax to read data from column y1 would be

```
data = df.loc[(x1,x2), y1] # full index should be passed to loc
data = df.loc[(3,3)] # zone=3 and run=3
```

Second line will store value of data as 20.493902